# Java most efficient way using a long epoch timestamp to detect a change in day

Tags: java, database, timestamp, long-integer, epoch

Problem situation: I have an incredibly high number of records all marked with a timestamp. I'm looping through all of them to do this and that but I need to detect when the day has changed.

Right now for each loop I'm doing:

```
cal.setTimeInMillis(record.time);
int currentDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Is this as slow as I imagine it is when it's running hundreds of thousands of times?
I imagine I'm missing a really simple modulo answer or something.

Edit: Time zone does not matter, the information I'm collecting more resolves around a consumable report for someone. 24 hours per report is more accurate, so realistically I don't have to worry about whether or not that's 5am - 5am or 3pm - 3pm, just that I was able to gather 24H worth of info.

Thanks all

Comment: Well, how exact do you want this to behave, how to deal with leap years, leap seconds, etc. a date library takes care of all that, but it will certainly take few nanoseconds to do that - have you actually measured the performance in a meaningful way, is it actually slow?

Comment: It's probably more efficient to convert the end of the day to a timestamp and compare that with the `record.time`

Comment: https://ideone.com/23p0Y6 1M iterations took 0.76s. Doesn't seem slow. I'd be more concerned about the correctness of it (e.g. are you calculating the day in the correct timezone).

Comment: Added an edit, I don't actually have to worry about time zone really, I just want to split into 24 hour chunks.

Comment: What are the limits of your 24-hour chunks? Do you mean to start with the current moment and go forward/backward in 24-hour increments from there? You need to think this through more clearly. Saying “when the day has changed” while also saying “split into 24-hour chunks” is a contradiction. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: I was unclear. I get the records back in order (newest to oldest). The 24 hour chunks could start from the first record, it would not be a big deal to dispose of the last chunk that wouldn't be a perfect 24 hours.

Comment: It seems that you are using `Calendar`. I recommend you don’t. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `Instant` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0):

After Andy Turner’s time test I am not necessarily convinved that you need any optimized solution. In any case, timsmelik’s suggestion is pretty straightforward: convert the time when the day changes to a count of milliseconds since the epoch so you only need to compare `long` values. I don’t find that it hurts readability very badly. So here it is in code. I am using and warmly recommending java.time, the modern Java date and time API, if only for the conversion from hours to milliseconds and for printing the results. Even when such a conversion seems trivial, it’s always best to leave to the standard library to do it. It’s more self-explanatory and less error-prone, and it’s easier for the reader to convince oneself that it’s correct.

```
    final long twentyfourHoursAsMillis = Duration.ofHours(24).toMillis();
    
    // Times are already sorted descending (from newest to oldest)
    long[] times = { 1_611_718_370_000L, 1_611_632_000_000L,
                     1_611_631_970_000L, 1_611_459_150_000L };
    List<List<Long>> chunks = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Long> currentChunk  = new ArrayList<>();
    
    // Process first time separately to get started
    currentChunk.add(times[0]);
    long timeOfNextChunk = times[0] - twentyfourHoursAsMillis;
    // Process remaining times
    for (int i = 1; i < times.length; i++) {
        long currentTime = times[i];
        if (currentTime <= timeOfNextChunk) {
            chunks.add(currentChunk);
            currentChunk = new ArrayList<>();
            do {
                timeOfNextChunk -= twentyfourHoursAsMillis;
            } while (currentTime <= timeOfNextChunk);
        }
        
        currentChunk.add(currentTime);
    }
    // Save last chunk, why not?
    chunks.add(currentChunk);
    
    // Print result
    for (List<Long> chunk : chunks) {
        String chunkAsString = chunk.stream()
                .map(Instant::ofEpochMilli)
                .map(Instant::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
        System.out.println(chunkAsString);
    }
```

Output is:

> ```
> 2021-01-27T03:32:50Z, 2021-01-26T03:33:20Z
> 2021-01-26T03:32:50Z
> 2021-01-24T03:32:30Z
> ```

I am printing `Instant` objects. They always print in UTC. For your situation you may want to do otherwise if you need to print the times at all.

You should add a check of your assumption that the times come in sorted order.

I have taken your word for it and broken into chunks at 24 hours. 24 hours may not even mean 5am - 5am but could mean for instance from 5 AM EST on March 13 to *6 AM EDT* on March 14 because summer time (DST) has begun in the meantime. If you prefer to split at the same clock hour, the code can be modified to do that.